# TCP Socket fast packet sending

Tags: c#, sockets, tcp

I have a class of the logged in the clients:

```
public class LoggedIn_Class
{
    public Socket socket;
    public string name;
}
```

And I have a list:

```
public static List<Object> LoggedIn_List = new List<Object>();
```

When someone login to my server I add it to the list:

```
LoggedIn_Class newClient = new LoggedIn_Class();

newClient.socket = currentSocket;
newClient.name = currentName;

LoggedIn_List.Add(newClient);
```

Now I'm trying to send a packet to every client with this:

```
foreach (LoggedIn_Class s in variables.LoggedIn_List.ToArray())
{
   s.socket.Send(Packet);
}
```

Now the problem is the foreach processing too fast the items and it can't be send. This works properly, but I don't think this is the best solution...

```
foreach (LoggedIn_Class s in variables.LoggedIn_List.ToArray())
{
   s.socket.Send(Packet);
   Thread.Sleep(50);
}
```

Someone have any idea about this? What can I do to wait the end of the send?

Comment: What kind of socket are you using? What protocol? Is there an exception? How does it "not work"?

Comment: `Socket.Send` is a sync operation - that is it returns only after your data has been sent. You seem to confuse it with async (by way you describe it and looking at your approach). Something else is going wrong here. Do you get any exceptions or what's the problem?

Comment: I'm using TCP sockets. The client just not receive the packets, it don't have any exception.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I'm using TCP sockets. The client just not receive the packets, it don't have any exception.

There are plenty of answers about this. You real problem is that you have not understood what stream based protocols means. With TCP you do not send messages, you send streams of bytes.

As a result, the receiver side can not assume that everything received in one `socket.Receive` corresponds to exactly the same bytes as the other side sent using `socket.Send`.

You should therefore use some sort of mechanism to detect when a complete message have been received. Typically you either prefix each of your messages with a length prefix or use a delimiter after each message.

The reason to why it works when you use a `Thread.Sleep` is that the messages are short enough to be sent one at a time and you manage to receive them before the next message is sent. Without the delay, the [nagle algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nagle%27s_algorithm) probably comes into play and merge your messages.

A naive implementation:

```
public void Send(byte[] msg)
{
    var header = BitConverter.GetBytes(msg.Length);
    socket.Send(header, 0, header.Length);
    socket.Send(msg, 0, msg.Length);
}
```

Receiver side (probably faulty, but should give you a hint):

```
var buffer = new byte[4];
int bytesReceived = socket.Receive(buffer, 0, 4, ....);
if (bytesReceived < 4)
{
     bytesReceived = socket.Receive(buffer, bytesReceived, 4 - bytesReceived, ....);
     //this can fail too, probably should use a loop like below until
     //all four length bytes have been received.
}

var bytesToRead = BitConverter.GetInt32(buffer, 0);
var buffer = new byte[bytesToRead];
var offset = 0;

while (bytesToRead  > 0)
{
   var len = Math.Min(bytesToRead, buffer.Length);
   var read = socket.Receive(buffer, offset, len, .....);
   bytesToRead -= read;
   offset += read;
}

//now you got everything.
```

Comment: Thank you for this great answer, but what do you recommend now? I should switch to UDP? I'm converting classes to byte arrays and I trying to send that to every client. My classes contains usually strings, ints and bools.

Comment: Use WCF or prefix the byte arrays with an int. UDP is not reliable nor send messages in order. UDP is therefore more complex to use if you must receive every sent message and in the correct order.

Comment: What do you mean as prefix the byte arrays with an int? The first byte of my packet always the header and on client-side I have a switch of the headers. Or you don't mean this? Sorry for my bad English, but I don't really get it.

Comment: Updated with a small example